# Rewrite host and port for outgoing request of a pod in an Istio Mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh

I have to get the existing microservices run. They are given as docker images.
They talk to each other by configured hostnames and ports.
I started to use Istio to view and configure the outgoing calls of each microservice.
Now I am at the point that I need to rewrite / redirect the host and the port of a request that goes out of one container.
How can I do that with Istio?

I will try to give a minimum example.
There are two services, service-a and service-b.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-b
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: service-b
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: service-b
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service-b
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-b
  labels:
    run: service-b
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      name: service-b
  selector:
    run: service-b

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: service-a
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: service-a
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service-a
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-a
  labels:
    run: service-a
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      name: service-a
  selector:
    run: service-a
```

I can docker exec into service-a and successfully execute:

```
root@service-a-d44f55d8c-8cp8m:/# curl -v service-b:8080

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: envoy
```

Now, to simulate my problem, I want to reach service-b by using another hostname and port. I want to configure Istio the way that this call will also work:

```
root@service-a-d44f55d8c-8cp8m:/# curl -v service-x:7777
```

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: For your task you can look at [virtual services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) and [destination rules](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/). For better help please consider adding [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a form of yaml manifests of services, exact task you need to achieve

Comment: Which `istio` version is used? I'd like to replicate the setup and see what can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions which can be used depending on necessity of using `istio` features.

If no `istio` features are planned to use, it can be solved using native kubernetes. In turn, if some `istio` feature are intended to use, it can be solved using `istio virtual service`. Below are two options:

---

**1. Native kubernetes**

`Service-x` should be pointed to the backend of `service-b` deployment. Below is `selector` which points to `deployment: service-b`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-x
  labels:
    run: service-x
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 7777
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      name: service-x
  selector:
    run: service-b
```

This way request will go through `istio` anyway because sidecar containers are injected.

```
# curl -vI service-b:8080

*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx:8080...
* Connected to service-b (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 8080 (#0)
> Host: service-b:8080
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: envoy
```

and

```
# curl -vI service-x:7777

*   Trying yy.yy.yy.yy:7777...
* Connected to service-x (yy.yy.yy.yy) port 7777 (#0)
> Host: service-x:7777
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: envoy
```

---

**2. Istio virtual service**

In this example [virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service) is used. Service `service-x` still needs to be created, but now we don't specify any selectors:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-x
  labels:
    run: service-x
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 7777
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      name: service-x
```

Test it from another pod:

```
# curl -vI service-x:7777

*   Trying yy.yy.yy.yy:7777...
* Connected to service-x (yy.yy.yy.yy) port 7777 (#0)
> Host: service-x:7777
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< server: envoy
```

`503` error which is expected. Now creating `virtual service` which will route requests to `service-b` on `port: 8080`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-x-to-b
spec:
  hosts:
  - service-x
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service-b
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Testing from the pod:

```
# curl -vI service-x:7777

*   Trying yy.yy.yy.yy:7777...
* Connected to service-x (yy.yy.yy.yy) port 7777 (#0)
> Host: service-x:7777
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: envoy
```

See it works as expected.

---

Useful links:

- [Istio virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service)
- [virtual service - destination](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Destination)